# Turning On HTML5 Native Form Validation For WordPress Comments?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, validation

On line 2022 in wp-includes/comment-template.php WordPress 3.7.1 sets the form attribute to 'novalidate.' I don't see a hook to change that.

How do I convince WordPress to leave that attribute off so that native HTML5 form validation is active?

Bob

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress Codex, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com


Comment: I'm sorry about that, I hadn't heard of wordpress.stackexchange.com. Now I have!

Answer (score 2):

There's no filter to modify that attribute. You could remove it with jQuery:

```
$("#commentform").removeAttr("novalidate");
```

Comment: I see. Is that to suggest that WordPress does not "support" HTML5 native validation? They seem to be making it harder to use.

Comment: I'd suggest you browse the Trac for WP core to find out the rationale behind it http://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=novalidate

Comment: Thanks for the link. There seems to be a lot of good stuff there!

Comment: WordPress supports HTML5, does not imply that it supports all features in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `novalidate` attribute with this simple Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var commentForm = document.getElementById('commentform'); 
    commentForm.removeAttribute('novalidate');
</script>
```

No jQuery needed.

You can include the following code to run script just on posts:

#### footer.php

```
<?php if( is_singular() ) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var commentForm = document.getElementById('commentform');
        commentForm.removeAttribute('novalidate');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function rather than `comment_form()`

```
function validate_comment_form(){
    ob_start();
    comment_form();
    echo str_replace('novalidate','data-toggle="validator" ',ob_get_clean());
}
```